# How to analyze multiple Likert-scale data?

Tags: anova, likert

I have been stuck in a problem recently. 
I designed a survey, in which the participants observed several images. These images are gathered from different cultures, e.g. Culture A, Culture B and Culture C. For each image, I asked the participants a question: To what extent do you believe this image comes from each culture and three Likert-scales from 1-5 (1 for completely disbelieve, 5 for completely believe) are offered. 
After gathering the answers, I'd like to do some analysis on the them.  Since culture B and C have more similarities with each other than they with culture A,  what I'd like to know is,  after observing an image, if the extent on believing it from culture B and C are more 'similar' or their distributions show no significant difference. What I am considering is one-way ANOVA (since there are 3 groups) or pairwise t-test (since the variables are somewhat correlated), which is more proper for this issue?

Hope someone could offer me some suggestions.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with variables on the ordinal scale (categorical variable with ordering), a first step can be to start by looking at the correlation matrix using [Spearmans rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and directly investigate the correlation between culture B and C, for example, and then move on from there.